# Hibernate + Mysql grammar error when select from a table with unicode characters

Tags: mysql, hibernate, unicode, collation, utf8mb4

In my db, there is a table with a column that may contain Unicode characters that are entered by end users. I have configured my hibernate mysql connection in a property file as given below.

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

For DB table and the column, I use utf8mb4 charset with utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation.

Above configuration works fine for inserting into the table that has the column I mentioned above. user can enter the unicode characters from the UI and they get saved fine in the table.

Then, there is this big join query I use to retrieve some set of user data which includes aforementioned Unicode data too. There, at the runtime, I get a MySql grammar error.

In the query, I check if the search param is null. That is where the exception is thrown from when the param is null.

```
"..... where (:fromDate is null or bt.created_date >= :fromDate) and (:toDate is null or bt.created_date <= :toDate) and ...... "
```

Error log:

> ................... You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'where (null is null or bt.created_date >= null)
> ........

I tried adding `&characterSetResults=UTF-8` also to the connection string with no luck.

What is the issue here. How can I get this fixed.

**EDIT:**

It turned out that the issue has nothing to do with the join I have mentioned. Even without the table with unicode data, issue still happens. When unicode configs are removed from the connection strings only, it works fine.

May be a issue with mismatching charsets and collations between db and client ?

Comment: you can't put placeholders on the left sight

Comment: It's complaining at `WHERE` _or just before that_.  So, please show us the earlier part of the query.

Comment: @nbk, how would I handle the scenarios where the placeholder is null? Note that this works fine when i remove all the unicode related configs from connection string

Comment: @RickJames it goes as ```"inner join table_1 tsc on bt.table_one_id = tsc.id "```

Comment: Show us the complete query, i think you still can#t make :fromDate is null and then replace the place holder, you shoild check the data before you add it to the query

Comment: Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- there may be something subtle in the charset specifications.